# EF6 takes 5 mins to run query on less then 40,000 records

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am running into a very odd error with EF6. I have uploaded ~38K records on my first pass. Then on my second round, I query the table with a conditional  linq statement. That line of code takes about 4 mins to run. This are my entities.

```
[Table("RAW_ADWORDS")] 
public class AdWord
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public bool Processed { get; set; }
    public string Client { get; set; }
    public long ClientID { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public bool ProcessedAllFile { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastTimeRun{ get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastDateTimeProcessed { get; set; }
    public virtual List<AdWordCampaign> Campaigns { get; set; }
}

[Table("foobar")] 
public class AdWordCampaign
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Campaign { get; set; }
    public long CampaignID { get; set; }
    public string Day { get; set; }
    public long Clicks { get; set; }
    public string CampaignStatus { get; set; }
    public long Cost { get; set; }
    public long Impressions { get; set; }
    public double CTR { get; set; }
    public long AvgCPC { get; set; }
    public double AvgPosition { get; set; }
    public DateTime DownloadDate { get; set; }
}
```

}

First I run this:

```
AdWord objAdWord = adwordsContext.AdWords.Where(c => c.ClientID == iCampaignID).FirstOrDefault();
```

Then

```
AdWordCampaign objAdWordCampaign = objAdWord.Campaigns.Where(c => c.CampaignID == iElementCampaignID && c.Day == sElementDate).FirstOrDefault();
```

The line above seems to load ALL the records first before it does the query. Also it still takes 4 mins if I add a Take(5) in the query.

Comment: Do you have index on `ClientID`? If not, it will scan the whole table, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this info will be useful.

1. Try to add indexes to fields of your table you are including to WHERE in LINQ.
2. You can always can create extra Views and add it into EF model and do LINQ to them. It will reduce time as well.
3. If you expect 1 record always try to use `SingleOrDefault`

Comment: I would have assumed it was indexed. How do I do that with code? Assuming EF is a C# tool, I wouldn't expect MS to have C# create the table, handing it a DBA to index it and then hand it back, though this is a good idea.

Comment: @user3521111 See the following link for clues on how to "demand" indexes on your tables: **http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2014/02/15/ef-6-1-creating-indexes-with-indexattribute/**

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
objAdWord.Campaigns.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CampaignID == iElementCampaignID && c.Day == sElementDate)
```

`.Where` is an O(n) operation, I'm not sure if the `Where` then `FirstOrDefault` clause would be optimized but if it's not you're wasting a lot of time using `Where`. To improve performance further, ensure that `CampaignID` is indexed

Comment: I saw another thread recently that said that it's sometimes faster to do Where before First, but this is definitely worth a shot.

Comment: I don't see why it would be. Where would iterate over every result, whereas First would stop at the first one.

Comment: The SQL it generates is basically the same, because it takes the Where and the First and compiles them into one single query. Generally, they really shouldn't have much difference at all.

Comment: I didn't know that, I am not able to look at the SQL :p If the SQL is compiled (as I suspected it might have been) then I don't know what else to suggest other than indexing.

Comment: you should try LinqPad. It allows you to type Linq queries and see exactly what the resulting SQL looks like. It's also very good at optimizing problems like this because it gives you an easy place to run the queries without running any code (basically SSMS for linq:) )

Comment: I do use LINQPad, however I never look at the compiled SQL section :(

Comment: well maybe you should! you can learn a lot about what changes will have an actual affect on performance. Try typing in a Where(x).First() and a First(x), you'll see the SQL is usually the exact same :)

Comment: ex: `Persons.Where(x => x.FirstName.StartsWith("a")).First().Dump();
Persons.First(x => x.FirstName.StartsWith("a")).Dump();` outputs `SELECT TOP (1) FirstName, ...
FROM [Person] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[FirstName] LIKE @p0`
`GO`

`SELECT TOP (1) FirstName, ...
FROM [Person] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[FirstName] LIKE @p0`

Comment: DLeh. GREAT IDEA. I downloaded it and ran the same query. Took 00:00.125. So what now?

Answer (score 0):

You need to watch the queries that are generated & executed on the server and make sure they're optimized.

If you're using MS SQL Server, you want to run the SQL Server Profiler tool.  Put breakpoints in your code before you call the method that executes the query. Clear the profiler's display, then execute the method.  You can capture the SQL from there, then put it into SSMS and view the plan.  If the query doesn't use indexes, you need to add indexes that it will use the next time it runs.

I've only ever used Database First, not Code First, so I don't know how you tell Entity Framework to create indexes in the Code First scenario, sorry.  But you still need to optimize all of your queries.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before with EF when referencing linked objects through a "primary object" - i.e. when you do

`AdWordCampaign objAdWordCampaign = objAdWord.Campaigns.Where(...).FirstOrDefault();`.

Quite simply it iterates all records one-by-one - and hence the slow query.

If you change to the following, you should get an almost instant response:

```
AdWord objAdWord = adwordsContext.AdWords.Where(c => c.ClientID == iCampaignID).FirstOrDefault();

AdWordCampaign objAdWordCampaign = <adwordsContext>.Campaigns
.Where(c => <c.AdwordId = objAdWord.Id> && c.CampaignID == iElementCampaignID && c.Day == sElementDate)
.FirstOrDefault();
```

I've put changes in angular brackets and I'm not sure which property within an AdWordCampaign marks the Id of the AdWord for the relationship from a glance at your model, but I'm sure you get the idea - go direct to Capaigns table via the context, using the AdWord as an addiitonal `Where` clause, rather than via the AdWord's Campaigns collection.